# list-style-image not displaying image

Tags: html, css

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

*For unordered lists directly after h2 headings nested within the section element, create a style rule that displays the image file flake.png as the bullet marker.*

**What I am using to try to accomplish this: (Unsuccessful)**

```
section h2>ul {
    list-style-image: url(flake.png);
}
```

Instead of doing the above, I removed 'section h2>' from the selector, and it worked using what is below.

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url(flake.png);
}
```

Obviously what is above is not what is required in the instructions, so I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Better to say your selector doesn't match the proper element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For unordered lists directly after h2 headings nested within the section element

```
section > h2 + ul {
    list-style-image: url(flake.png);
}
```

> The PLUS is referred to as an adjacent selector. It will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element.

```css
section > h2 + ul {
  list-style: square;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <h2>Some Heading</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>Affected</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Not affected</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**Article @ Tuts+** - [**The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me so quickly. What you have suggested works perfectly. I now understand how to do this!